Как скачать определенную папку с рерозитория
Как скачать только папку https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.compiler/share/classes/javax и все ее содержимое?
Команда wget -r -np -l inf (url) скачивает только файл javax/tools. git скачивает весь репозиторий.
Как это исправить?

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content
